# Toggling between 2 graphs in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

Hello I was wondering if there is a way I could toggle between 2 graphs(pyGal graphs) which I'm creating in python and passing through flask to the jinja template. I have a graph for weekly information and monthly information and I want (Not a button) but some sort of thing I could click to show only 1 at a time. I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Here on SO it's better to already have a few lines of code that show your effort on the topic you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how your webpage is designed. You have to think if the user will understand if you don't put a button or something that relates in an obvious way to that change.

Sometimes we design something that we think that is obvious but if the end user doesn't understand it, it's of no use.

If in your page you have more data showing information about week or month, maybe it's better to put a button that filters it by Month/Week. Just one tiny one :)

If you send a picture with the template I can try to give you some ideas.